# Is HAVING ever necessary for non-aggregated grouped columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some code that generates SQL and need to understand if HAVING is ever necessary (or useful) for non-aggregated grouped columns?  I haven't found any examples that suggest it is but wanted to check here.

The MySQL docs has this comment "The SQL standard requires that HAVING must reference only columns in the GROUP BY clause or columns used in aggregate functions."

I know that HAVING is necessary for aggregated conditions on groups, and also understand that WHERE can be used for non-aggregated grouped columns (which can be more efficient than having), but my questions is this:

Is HAVING ever necessary (or useful) for non-aggregated grouped columns?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "non-aggregated grouped columns?" Example?

Comment: I have attempted to use it (on SQL Server) for tricking the optimizer into delaying the evaluation of some conditions. I don't remember the specifics. And while I recall seeing differences in the execution plan I don't think it gave me the outcome I hoped for.

Comment: @ExplosionPills OP means (I think) that there are non-aggregated columns in select clause which we also group by and to include conditions on them in having clause.

Comment: @KamilG. thanks I think that makes sense; in this case it would make sense to use `WHERE` to me for those conditions

Comment: @KamilG That's what I meant, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HAVING` is specifically designed for aggregated columns.  MySQL allows non-aggregated columns in the `HAVING` clause.  There are three use-cases, that I can think of:

1. An efficiency hack, when the values of the group having identical values for the group.
2. An error, which should be avoided.
3. An efficiency hack, when there is no aggregation.

The first could conceivably be used in a situation like this:

```
select l.*, sum(x.y)
from list l join 
     . . .
group by l.listid
having l.foo = 'bar';
```

This works because all `l.foo` should have the same value for a given `l.listid` (assuming `l.listid` is a primary key).  In this case, this filters the data as if you used `where`.

BUT, if this condition is not true, then the `HAVING`/`WHERE` equivalence is not true.  The `HAVING` will choose a value from an indeterminate row and then filter the resulting aggregation column.  The `WHERE` does the filtering before the aggregation.  So, if lists could have the same type and you do:

```
select l.*, sum(x.y)
from list l join 
     . . .
group by l.type
having l.foo = 'bar';
```

This is a badly formed query (hence an error in my opinion), but is not equivalent to moving the condition to the `WHERE`.

The third situation is where there is no aggregation:

```
select l.*, concat('a', 'b', 'c') as test
from list l
having test = 'abc';
```

This is a convenience in MySQL.  Other dialects would use a subquery.  MySQL materializes subqueries, introducing inefficiency.

Comment: This answer provides a great insight on the matter regarding MySQL. Normally database engineers and sql ninjas advise against using non aggregated columns in select clause despite the fact that this engine allows you to.

Answer (score 1):

No.

`WHERE` condition is applied before the rows are grouped, `HAVING` is applied on the grouped rows. If no aggregated column is used, you're selecting based on a single row value anyways, so the only (semantic) difference is whether the rows will be selected before grouping or after it - but the result will be the same.

(Note that this difference may not even be true in practice, the optimizer might reorder the operations.)